# asp.net mvc ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

```
 <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditOrganizationMeta", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "\<%= OrganizationMeta.vcr_MetaKey + Lang.int_LangId%>" }))
                { %>
```

i want to specify name after UpdateTargetid ,how will i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already in a code block.  Just use the variables normally.

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditOrganizationMeta",
                          new AjaxOptions {
                                 UpdateTargetId = OrganizationMeta.vcr_MetaKey
                                                     + Lang.int_LangId
                          })) 
   { %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize multiple items in a collection by simply providing a comma between the items.

```
new AjaxOptions { 
                  UpdateTargetId = "\<%= OrganizationMeta.vcr_MetaKey + Lang.int_LangId%>",
                  Name = "whatever" 
}
```